# Tomcat adds context-path to urls

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, hyperlink

In my application every link generated is surrounded by response.ecodeURL. On some servers encodeURL adds the context-path to the URL.

The application is named "appl". Creating a link /a/b/c.jsp creates on DEV-system the url /a/b/c.jsp, on Prod it creates /appl/a/b/c.jsp

The tomcat is behind an Apache Webserver which connects via ajp, not sure if thats a relevant fact.

EDIT:
The Webserver isn't relevant. I tried going directly on port 8080 and the same happend again.

Comment: The methods `HttpServletResponse.encodeURL` and `HttpServletResponse.encodeRedirectURL` should never prepend the context path. Some other component must be doing this for you.

When you say "creating a link /a/b/c.jsp", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I write something like <a href="<c:url value="/a/b/c.jsp" />">Link</a> to HTML

Answer (score 0):

`<c:url>` always pre-pends the context path to URLs: this is standard practice and should always be done. If you are using `<c:url>` then you shouldn't add your own prefix. Also note that `<c:url>` runs the URL through `HttpServletResponse.encodeURL` for you. That method adds URL-based session-tracking information (e.g. the ";jsessionid" path parameter) if appropriate.

You should *always* add the context prefix to all URLs, whether you use something like `<c:url>` or do it yourself. You just shouldn't do both. When you use the ROOT context, the context path with be `""` (i.e. empty string) and nothing will be pre-pended to your URLs.